# I have a TextInput, how to enable only numbers less than 9999.99?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a text input, how is possible to allow only numbers lower than 9999.99?

```
   <TextInput
                    autoFocus
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    placeholder="0.00"
                    keyboardType="numeric"
                    maxLength={9}
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                    placeholderTextColor={Colors.white}
                    underlineColorAndroid={Colors.transparent}
                    value={billAmount}
                    onChangeText={this.handleTextChange}
                    selection={{start: cursor, end: cursor}}
                  />
```

Here is handleTextChange function:

```
handleTextChange = (text) => {
    const { cursor, billAmount } = this.state
    let newText
        newText = text.replace(/[^1-9]/g, '')
        this.setState({
          billAmount: newText
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex expression also removes any dots (`.`). This will lead you loosing any floats. If you want to enable floats you need to add `.` to your regex.

Then all you need to do is to parse your text to float and check if it is lower that the max float.

**Sample**

```
handleTextChange = (text) => {
    const newAmount = parseFloat(text.replace(/[^1-9.]/g, ''));
    this.setState({
      billAmount: newAmount > 10000 ? '9999.99' : newAmount + ''
    });
  }
```

Comment: Hm, theoretically, it looks correct, however, I'm still able to enter numbers more than 9999.99

Comment: @Lucky_girl I found out that `value` prop needs to be a string and not a number. Updated my sample.